# Mysql: find active users who logged in once a week

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `users` and another table `logins` everytime the user log-in into the website we record a row in `logins` ex.

```
Users
-----
14 | name1
17 | name2
20 | name3
21 | name4
25 | name5

logins
----
14 | 2015-03-01
14 | 2015-03-07
14 | 2015-03-16
14 | 2015-03-24
14 | 2015-03-30
17 | 2015-03-01
17 | 2015-03-07
17 | 2015-03-16
17 | 2015-03-17
17 | 2015-03-30
20 | 2015-03-01
20 | 2015-03-07
20 | 2015-03-08
20 | 2015-03-16
20 | 2015-03-25
20 | 2015-03-30
```

if start date is `2015-03-01` and end date is `2015-04-01` then `14 & 20` should be selected while `17` wont be selected since he didn't login in the week of `03-22` to `03-28` so the result would be

```
   Result
   ------
   2
```

Comment: I didn't understand the question correctly. How would you calculate week? From midnidht sunday to midnight sunday? Can you please give a more elaborate example and sample output based on that?

Comment: So how you define your week start and week end ?

Comment: @Utsav thanks i updated the question for a better example

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty sunday or monday doesn't matter i can change it to match my needs as long as it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you get the list of users per week which has logged in at least once, then you count per month the amount of users:

```
SELECT LoginYear,LoginWeek,COUNT(*) as NumbUsers
FROM (
  SELECT Year(logins.date) as LoginYear, Week(logins.date) as LoginWeek, logins.UserID
  FROM logins
  WHERE logins.date>='2015-03-01'
  GROUP BY LoginYear, LoginWeek, logins.UserID
  HAVING COUNT(*)>0
) t
GROUP BY LoginYear,LoginWeek;
```

**Week numbering:** MySQL can count the weeks in different ways (such as starting on a Sunday/Monday) using the mode: `WEEK(date,mode)`. See the [`WEEK` MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week).

---

**Update:** to get the number of persons which has been logged in at least once every week: first we get the users that were logged in at least once per week in the subquery `weektable`. Then the users are select which have a week count which equals the total number of weeks in that period (thus having been online each week). Finally we count those users.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM (
   SELECT UserID
   FROM (
     SELECT Year(logins.date) as LoginYear, Week(logins.date) as LoginWeek, logins.UserID
     FROM logins
     WHERE logins.date>='2015-03-01'
     GROUP BY LoginYear, LoginWeek, logins.UserID
     HAVING COUNT(*)>0
   ) weektable
   GROUP BY UserID
   HAVING COUNT(*)>=TIMESTAMPDIFF(WEEK,'2015-03-01',NOW())
) subq;
```

**Note 1:** I put the date '2015-03-01' as an example but you can change this or put as a variable.

**Note 2:** depending on the dates you choose it can be that the week count by `TIMESTAMPDIFF` is less than the maximum number of weeks (counted by `COUNT(*)`), since it does not count half weeks. Therefore I put `>=` in the last line: `HAVING COUNT(*)>=TIMESTAMPDIFF(WEEK,'2015-03-01',NOW())`.

Comment: thank you for your answer. this would show the total number of users that logged in for any given week in that range. what i need is the total number of users that logged in EVERY week since the start date

Answer (score -1):

I cannot test it here at the moment but something like

```
SELECT COUNT(Users.id) WHERE logins.date>=XXXX AND logins.date<=XXXX GROUP BY Users.id
```

should work

Comment: this would not exclude users who logged in week 1 Sept but not week 2 Sept

Comment: Not nice to give me a negative vote for an answer which was correct for your not clear defined quetion.